# Repetition when clicking the header

Tags: javascript, jquery

Good Day,
I am displaying a table where the content is extracted from PHP/MySQL.
When the mouse hovers the head of the table, a small down arrow appears and disapears when the mouse leaves. I want to be able to sort the column by clicking on the header.
For some reason, when I click once on some columns (not always the same!) I have 2 times a result in the console (see screenshot).
Here is my code:

```
<table id="db" style="white-space:nowrap;display:block;margin:5px;">
    <tr>
        <th id="sortByName" style="border:1px solid black;text-align:center;">Name</th>
        <th id="sortByFname" style="border:1px solid black;text-align:center;">Firstname</th>
        <th id="sortByTel" style="border:1px solid black;text-align:center;">Tel</th>
        <th id="sortByZip" style="border:1px solid black;text-align:center;">ZIP Code</th>
        <th id="sortByDate" style="border:1px solid black;text-align:center;">Birth Date</th>
    </tr>   
    <tbody>
        ...
    </tbody>     
</table>
```

Javascript portion:

```
 $("#db th").hover(function() {
        $(this).append("<i class='fa fa-caret-down' aria-hidden='true'></i>");
        $(this).click(function (e){
            e.preventDefault();

            var capture = $(this).attr('id');
            console.log("Captured: " + capture);

    }, function() {
        $(this).children("i").remove();
    });
 }
```

And the screen capture of the console:
[image]

I thought using `e.preventDefault();` would resolve the problem, but it's not.
Anybody can help ? Thanks in advance!

Comment: When are you assigning the .hover() to your #db th elements? Once the document is loaded, or after another certain event? Seems to me like this happens at the wrong timing. So please show a bit more of your javascript function.

Comment: The `:hover` element is fired as soon as the table is displayed.  This is the only code I have in my `$(document).ready(function() {...});`. I'm not sure it's a question of timing.

Answer (score 0):

I used `e.stopPropagation();` and `e.stopImmediatePropagation();` after `e.preventDefault();` and it seems working properly. Thank You for your help! :)